# Re-order stl vector using another stl vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

```
typedef struct tagSTUDENT
{
    UINT32 id;
    string name;

}STUDENT, *LP_STUDENT;

vector<LP_STUDENT> allStudents 
vector<LP_STUDENT> classA
```

I want students in class A to be at the beginning or end of allStudents. allStudents is not sorted. Also would the std::sort sort students based on id or some other criteria?

Would inserting classA at the end of allStudents & eliminating duplicates be a good way to go?

Comment: You need to define `operator<` for your struct for `std::sort` to work.

Comment: Look at the [std::partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) and [std::stable_partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) algorithms.

Comment: @GargAnkit that would not work as it is a vector of pointers. He would have to pass a custom comparator to `std::sort` .

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a vector of pointers instead of `vector<STUDENT>` ?

Comment: Yes. It helps for some other stuff. Do you have any suggestions if it were vector<STUDENT>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to use `std::partition()` for a `vector` of `Students`, the modification for a vector of pointers to students is straightforward but makes for more code. [Live version](http://ideone.com/uJEgRA). If you're dealing with large numbers of students you might want to do something more efficient to check for membership of class A like use a `set` or binary search on a sorted `vector`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    uint32_t id;
    string name;
};

bool operator==(const Student& a, const Student& b) {
    return tie(a.id, a.name) == tie(b.id, b.name);
}

main() {
    const auto jane = Student{3, "Jane"};
    const auto zippy = Student{1, "Zippy"};
    const auto classA = vector<Student>{jane, zippy};
    auto allStudents = vector<Student>{{5, "Rod"}, jane, {4, "Freddy"}, zippy, {2, "Bungle"}};
    partition(begin(allStudents), end(allStudents), [&](const auto& s){ return find(begin(classA), end(classA), s) == end(classA); });
    for (const auto& s : allStudents) cout << s.id << ", " << s.name << "; ";
    cout << endl; 
}
```

Output is:

```
5, Rod; 2, Bungle; 4, Freddy; 1, Zippy; 3, Jane;
```

If you really want to work with `vector<Student*>`s for some reason then the main change is to switch `find()` for `find_if()` in the `partition()` call lambda:

```
[&](const Student* s){ return find_if(begin(classA), end(classA), 
                              [&](const Student* x){ return *x == *s; }) == end(classA); }
```

Comment: I am dealing with a large number of students. If you could edit to provide an answer using pointers that'd be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @SunilMathew Edited to describe how to make this work with `vector<Student*>`s